# change carousel control next and prev button v4

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel, bootstrap-4

I want to change crousel control next and prev image button for carousel slider v4 but when they change the color of them has low opacity , i dont know why , can you help me!!

```
  <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide bg-inverse" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="carousel-item active"> <img class="d-block img-fluid ml-auto mr-auto" src="assets/images/banner0.png" alt="first slide">

                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3 class="animated fadeInDownBig">Network Security &</h3>
                            <h3 class="animated fadeInDownBig">Modern Data Center</h3>
                            <h3 class="animated fadeInUp">Networking Solutions</h3>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block img-fluid ml-auto mr-auto" src="assets/images/banner.png" alt="second slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3 class="animated fadeInDownBig">Network Security &</h3>
                            <h3 class="animated fadeInDownBig">Modern Data Center</h3>
                            <h3 class="animated fadeInUp">Networking Solutions</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block img-fluid ml-auto mr-auto" src="assets/images/banner3.png" alt="third slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3 class="animated fadeInDownBig">Network Security &</h3>
                            <h3 class="animated fadeInDownBig">Modern Data Center</h3>
                            <h3 class="animated fadeInUp">Networking Solutions</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="container">
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: better give more details what you try

Answer (score 3):

In Bootstrap v4, the next and prev carousel control icons are now SVG images. Therefore, you cannot directly use CSS style attributes to change the icon color (Still you can change the `background-color`). Here is a workaround for changing icon colors.

If you use the browser inspector on prev and next icons, you will see the following styles coming from `bootstrap.min.css`

```
.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url(....);
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url(....);
}
```

To change icon color, override the `fill` attribute in SVG code as below. (Default color: `%23fff`, New color: `%343A40`)

```
.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image : url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%343A40' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M1.5 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image : url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%343A40' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M4 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}
```

Now your carousal control icons must appear in a new color.